# Is the hadith "true scholars are those who speak... the truth against tyrant rulers" sahih?

Tags: hadith, sunni, source-identification

While reading a Turkish text, I saw an unreferenced hadith, which can be translated to English like this:

> True scholars are those who speak the right and the truth against
>   tyrant rulers without fear.

Is this a sahih Hadith (according to Sunni sources), or is there any sahih Hadith with similar meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following on a website. Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

> "The best (Jihad) is (to speak) a word of truth to an oppressive ruler." - [Sunan of Abu-Dawood, Hadith 4344](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/39/54)

Comment: It's similar. Quoting from Sunan Abu Dawood doesn't tell us anything about the authenticity though.

Comment: OP didn't ask for the authenticity of the Hadith.

Comment: @ashes999, I tried to look it up online, but couldn't find any reputable source. Do you think I should delete the answer?

Comment: the title of the question is "is this a saheeh hadith." So the OP is asking :) I don't think you should delete it. I think you should try to answer it, since you've already done half the work of locating what could be the same hadith in one of the six major books.

Comment: @Songo they are the six major collections of ahadith, you can find them on sunnah.com: Saheeh Bukhari, Saheeh Muslim, At-Tirmidi, Ibn Majah, Sunan Abu Dawud, and An-Nasaai.

Comment: @Songo Also known as [Al-Kutub al-Sittah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Kutub_al-Sittah) :)

Comment: @Noah for what it's worth, this hadith is graded "Sahih" by Shaykh al-Albani (http://www.archive.org/download/waq80519/80519.pdf 27 MB)

Comment: @Ansari: Thanks for that. I found some other posts where it was marked Sahih. But they were posted on a forum and I was not sure if they were authentic. I will go through the document and edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Ansari please edit it into the answer, if that's the case.

Comment: @ashes999: The book is in Arabic and I don't speak Arabic:(